# Web.Config issue with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I have a site that uses Worpress on part of it. I am having trouble with the index page.

[*With* index.php](http://www.usweatherinsurance.com/blog/index.php) the site loads the most recent posts, which is the desired action with the incorrect url. [*Without* index.php](http://www.usweatherinsurance.com/blog/), which is the desired url, the page loads the 404 template.

I have the site working locally correctly. The only thing I can think of, is the web.config is incorrectly routing this request. Since this is an area I don't deal well with, I was hoping to get some help to see if that was the issue.

Here is the web.config contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2-1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have index.php in the list of Default Documents. Add index.php to the list as shown below. You can also do this through the IIS settings for Default Document.

```
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.php" />
            <add value="index.asp" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Everything appears to be running correctly now.